# Recursively copy files cross-platform via npm script

Tags: npm, copy, cross-platform, npm-scripts, multiplatform

We have within a *package.json* build script a copy command (no we cant quickly change that).

Is there any solution we can make this work multiplatform with the same syntax easily?

I looked in several npm copy packages, but they don't transpile from windows to unix paths.

We basically need something like:

```json
"build": "doStuff && cp -r ../folder/ /dist/"
```

working for windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why isn't this among the most searched-for npm scripts question?!  I searched for it over and over.  I started writing up my own question, and then this finally percolated to the top five questions in the suggested list.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For a cross-platform solution consider utilizing the [shx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx) package.

1. Firstly `cd` to your project directory and run the following command to install it:

   ```
   npm i -D shx
   ```
2. Then redefine your `build` script in the `scripts` section of your *package.json* as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
      "build": "doStuff && shx cp -r ../folder/ ./dist/"
   }
   ```