# How to generic copy a file with npm postbuild script

Tags: npm-scripts

I'm running `yarn run build`, which will re-create the directory *build* of my project. The thing is: whenever this is done, I lose one file that I must have inside of *build/*, which I manually copy and paste there.

So, naturally, I created the following script inside of *package.json* in order to have it done automatically:

```json
  "scripts": { 
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "npm run copy", 
    "copy": "copy Staticfile build"
  },
```

Now the thing is: will it work on Mac? Linux? I only have an Windows so I don't know and cannot test either, but I assume that it wouldn't work since `copy` statement is native on windows but not on other OS...

So the question is: how to make it be generic and OS-independent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> *"I assume that it wouldn't work since `copy` statement is native on windows but not on other OS"*

Yes, your assumption is correct.

On UNIX-like platforms *(Linux, macOS, etc...)* the [`cp`](https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html) command is analogous to the [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) command available on Windows.

For cross-platform compatibility consider utilizing either of the following two solutions - both essentially use node.js to copy the file *(personally I'd choose *"Solution A"*)*.

---

**Solution A: Using a third party package**

Utilize the [`shx`](https://github.com/shelljs/shx) package which is described as follows:

> *"`shx` is a wrapper around [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) Unix commands, providing an easy solution for simple Unix-like, cross-platform commands in npm package scripts."*

1. Firstly `cd` to your project directory and run the following command to install it:

   ```
   npm i -D shx
   ```
2. Then redefine your `copy` script in the scripts section of your *package.json* as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "copy": "shx cp Staticfile build"
   }
   ```

<sub>**Note:** There are other packages that will meet your cross-platform requirement too, such as; [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles)</sub>.

---

**Solution B: Using a node.js built-in**

Alternatively, if you wanted to avoid adding more dependencies to your project you could consider using the *node.js* built-in [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module. For example the following script utilizes the [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) and [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) methods.

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "copy": "node -e \"const fs = require('fs'); const data = fs.readFileSync('Staticfile'); fs.writeFileSync('build/Staticfile', data);\""
}
```

This `copy` script (above) utilizes the node.js command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) to evaluate the inline JavaScript as follows:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('Staticfile');
fs.writeFileSync('build/Staticfile', data);
```

<sub>**Note:** If you wanted to take an approach similar to this previous example, i.e. excecute a custom node.js inside an npm script, you should probably consider using the [`fs.copyFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_mode_callback) method instead. I've just provided an example using `fs.readFileSync()` and `fs.writeFileSync()` because I know those methods work with very early versions on node.js - unlike `fs.copyFile()` which requires node.js `>=8.5.0`</sub>

Comment: btw. If in the future you wanted to recursively copy files cross-platform via npm script instead of just a single file, please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822554/recursively-copy-files-cross-platform-via-npm-script/59823713?%3Fr=SearchResults#59823713) - it essentially utilizes the same `shx` package as per _"Solution A"_  above.

Comment: it worked perfectly in my Windows! gotta wait for someone with other OS to try it out tho! thanks :D