# I'm getting errors trying to connect to my db.sqlite file using sql.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, sql.js

I have a simple vue vite ts app. I'm trying to replace the localstorage with a local database. So I found this `sql.js` library. I installed `sql.js` and `@types/sql.js` for typescript. I tried to connect to my `db.sqlite` file. But when I did so I got a bunch of errors in the console.

That's how I connect to the db.sqlite code:

```
import initSqlJs from "sql.js"

initSqlJs({
  locateFile: () => "./db.sqlite",
}).then(SQL => {
  const db = new SQL.Database()
  console.log(db)
})
```

And that's the errors:

```
wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation

failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 0a 2f 2f 20 @+0

Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 0a 2f 2f 20 @+0)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 0a 2f 2f 20 @+0

Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 0a 2f 2f 20 @+0). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I connect to my db.sqlite file?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . You shouldn't import sql.js twice. locateFile is for .wasm file, not .sqlite . See the explanation https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js?tab=readme-ov-file#usage . You need to put .wasm to public/ or make it available as a file in vite dist/ in some other way. You can check the requests in devtools network, it's seen here from which url .wasm is requested and whether it's available. It may be not a good idea at all to use it without the backend because you need to store .sqlite somehow

Comment: do you mean like that? ```initSqlJs({
  locateFile: () => "/db.wasm",
}).then(SQL => {
  const db = new SQL.Database()
  console.log(db)
})```

Comment: Yes. You can call it db.wasm as long as it's available through webserver, but it's still sql-wasm.wasm file, not database data

Comment: The db.wasm file is in the public folder, like you said. But I still have a bounch of errors. Thsis is the first one: ```wasm streaming compile failed: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(): expected 4 bytes, fell off end @+0```

Comment: Try to download /db.wasm by direct linking. It's supposed to be binary and match the content of sql-wasm.wasm that you copied

Comment: Now I tried to locate it like that: locateFile: () => "../node_modules/sql.js/dist/sql-wasm.wasm", And it worked

Comment: So should I create the .wasm file myself, or should I just use the one that's in the npm package?

Comment: It's specific to the setup and it's not expected that it will be available under the same  "../node_modules/..." url in production. Either copy it to public/ or make it to be available in another way (this seems to cover this case exactly https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806317/3731501), but make sure this .wasm exists in proj dist/ when you build the app. And yes, it's supposed to be exactly sql-wasm.wasm from the package, it's not an arbitrary file