# Web Assembly (WASM) errors in a Vite + Vue app using Realm Web SDK

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, realm, vite

I'm using MongoDB Realm / App Services to make a web front end for an existing iOS app.

The standard Realm Web SDK only permits authentication and backend functions, so I am trying to use the preview release of the Web Assembly version (`realm@12.0.0-browser.2`) so that I can use device sync and interact with a Realm object in the way I'm used to.

> Details at: [Get Started with Realm Web & Atlas Device Sync (Preview)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/sync/#std-label-web-sync)

I am just using the basic app scaffold created by Vite, and then importing Realm in `App.vue`. I am not (yet) using Realm anywhere else in the code.

`import Realm, { App } from "realm";`

As advised in the Realm SDK documentation, for the Web Assembly version I had to enable top-level await in `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      supported: {
        "top-level-await": true
      },
    },
  },
})
```

So this works without errors when I build and preview (`vite build` followed by `vite preview`).

However, when I do `npm run dev` (`vite`), the server starts as expected, but there are the following errors in the browser console:

[image: Console errors]

```
[Error] wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Unexpected response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'
    (anonymous function) (realm.js:726)
[Error] falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
    (anonymous function) (realm.js:727)
[Error] failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.Module doesn't parse at byte 0: module doesn't start with '\0asm'
    (anonymous function) (realm.js:717)
[Error] Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.Module doesn't parse at byte 0: module doesn't start with '\0asm')
    abort (realm.js:661)
    (anonymous function) (realm.js:718)
```

This doesn't happen if I build and preview, so I hope it won't actually be a problem, but I don't understand what is going on here and I'm curious about how to fix it for working during the development process.

---

### Edit

Thanks to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) for the answer. I tried using the custom middleware, but got errors that the file cannot be found.

The `.wasm` files are in `node_modules/realm/dist`, but it seems to be looking in `node_modules/.vite` instead.

This is the error if I use `const wasmPath = path.join(__dirname, req.url);` (i.e. without the `public` path component).

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<my_local_path>/vite-project/node_modules/.vite/deps/realm-js-wasm.wasm'

In the end I got it working by using the middleware solution and redirecting it to the Realm folder directly:

`const wasmPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/realm/dist', path.basename(req.url));`

Comment: You need to check the requests, it fails at .wasm, this can give some info on what's going on. This is specific to how wasm works in general and may need a special treatment depending on the setup (vite), like  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571129/how-to-use-embedded-webassembly-in-vite/75806317#75806317 . Can't say for Realm specifically

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks - this is helpful. I’ll investigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors indicate a problem with the MIME type expected for WASM modules and the way the WebAssembly module is being loaded or parsed, as in [this issue](https://github.com/mdn/webassembly-examples/issues/5): the Vite development server is not correctly serving the `.wasm` file with the `application/wasm` MIME type.

You can try and configure Vite to properly serve WASM files with the correct MIME type, modifying your [`vite.config.js`](https://vitejs.dev/config/) file to include custom middleware for handling `.wasm` files, as in [`mycelial/mycelial-js` issue 25](https://github.com/mycelial/mycelial-js/issues/25#issuecomment-1209464719):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

// Custom middleware to serve wasm files with the correct MIME type
const wasmMiddleware = () => {
  return {
    name: 'wasm-middleware',
    configureServer(server) {
      server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
        if (req.url.endsWith('.wasm')) {
          const wasmPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url);
          const wasmFile = fs.readFileSync(wasmPath);
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/wasm');
          res.end(wasmFile);
          return;
        }
        next();
      });
    },
  };
};

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), wasmMiddleware()],
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      supported: {
        "top-level-await": true
      },
    },
  },
})
```

That custom middleware checks for requests ending in `.wasm` and serves them with the correct `Content-Type` header. That assumes the `.wasm` files are located in a `public` directory at the root of your project.
And that would be tailored for development with Vite's dev server and assumes your production environment already correctly serves `.wasm` files with the appropriate MIME type, as the issue does not manifest when using `vite build` followed by `vite preview`.

---

> In the end I got it working by using the middleware option, but redirecting it to the Realm folder directly:
>
> `const wasmPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/realm/dist', path.basename(req.url));`

True: instead of serving `.wasm` files from a generic or incorrect path (like the `public` folder or the `.vite` cache), directly point to the actual location of these files within the `node_modules` directory. Adjust the path in the middleware function:

```js
const wasmMiddleware = () => {
  return {
    name: 'wasm-middleware',
    configureServer(server) {
      server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
        if (req.url.endsWith('.wasm')) {
          // Directly point to the .wasm file within the realm/dist directory
          const wasmPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/realm/dist', path.basename(req.url));
          try {
            const wasmFile = fs.readFileSync(wasmPath);
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/wasm');
            res.end(wasmFile);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to load WASM file:', error);
            next();
          }
          return;
        }
        next();
      });
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would never have got to that by myself. The `.wasm` files are in the `node_modules/realm/dist` folder, so I had to experiment with setting the path components to direct it there (see my edit), but I got it working. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris I have edited the answer to include, reference and illustrate your conclusion. Let me know if I misinterpreted anything.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks. The Mycelial link was helpful too!